# How to show full screen youtube video in your website?

Tags: youtube, fullscreen

I would like to show youtube video as fullscreen when a user click on a image from my web page. It shouldnt take me to the youtube website - so I can give "esc" and come back to my home page.
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Try (replace XXXX by YT ID)

http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=XXXX&vq=hd720

http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXX?hd=1&autoplay=1

Works for me.

Comment: @RavikumarV. You should tick the answer if it's the correct one for you.